# Can't generate code with JOOQ and MySQL Database over SSL connection

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, jooq

i'm trying to generate code from a MySQL database, which I connect to over SSL. I got 3 files from the guy who set up the database (client-cert.pem, client-key.pem, ca-cert.pem)

To connect to the database in Java I first had to solve another problem with the certificates. With the help of http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68957 and the answer from *"[17 Apr 2013 9:04] Alexander Soklakov"*, I mananged to get the JDBC connection to work as expected in my Java code.

But now I don't know where to configure SSL in JOOQs library.xml. Where do I provide the *.pem files? Or my created trust- & keystore? Without configuration of SSL I get

```
Jun 11, 2014 1:53:40 PM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
Information: Initialising properties  : ./library.xml
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

javax.net.ssl.SSLException
MESSAGE: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0

STACKTRACE:

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:72)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.negotiateSSLConnection(MysqlIO.java:4237)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1222)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2558)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1485)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.run(GenerationTool.java:206)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.main(GenerationTool.java:173)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.main(GenerationTool.java:160)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 396 ms ago.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:87)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.negotiateSSLConnection(MysqlIO.java:4237)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1222)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2558)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1485)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.run(GenerationTool.java:206)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.main(GenerationTool.java:173)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.main(GenerationTool.java:160)
Jun 11, 2014 1:53:41 PM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger error
Schwerwiegend: Cannot read ./library.xml. Error : Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

javax.net.ssl.SSLException
MESSAGE: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0

STACKTRACE:

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:72)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.negotiateSSLConnection(MysqlIO.java:4237)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1222)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2558)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1485)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.run(GenerationTool.java:206)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.main(GenerationTool.java:173)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.main(GenerationTool.java:160)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 396 ms ago.
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

javax.net.ssl.SSLException
MESSAGE: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0

STACKTRACE:

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:72)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.negotiateSSLConnection(MysqlIO.java:4237)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1222)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2558)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1485)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.run(GenerationTool.java:206)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.main(GenerationTool.java:173)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.main(GenerationTool.java:160)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 396 ms ago.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:87)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.negotiateSSLConnection(MysqlIO.java:4237)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1222)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2558)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1485)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.run(GenerationTool.java:206)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.main(GenerationTool.java:173)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.main(GenerationTool.java:160)
Jun 11, 2014 1:53:41 PM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger error
Schwerwiegend: Usage : GenerationTool <configuration-file>
```

My library.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-2.5.0.xsd">
  <!-- Configure the database connection here -->
  <jdbc>
    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:mysql://server:3306/dbname?useSSL=true&amp;requireSSL=true&amp;verifyServerCertificate=false;</url>
    <user>user</user>
    <password>pass</password>
  </jdbc>

  <generator>
    <!-- The default code generator. You can override this one, to generate your own code style
         Defaults to org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator -->
    <name>org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator</name>

    <database>
      <!-- The database type. The format here is:
           org.util.[database].[database]Database -->
      <name>org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDatabase</name>

      <!-- The database schema (or in the absence of schema support, in your RDBMS this
           can be the owner, user, database name) to be generated -->
      <inputSchema>dbname</inputSchema>

      <!-- All elements that are generated from your schema (several Java regular expressions, separated by comma)
           Watch out for case-sensitivity. Depending on your database, this might be important! -->
      <includes>smv_.*</includes>

      <!-- All elements that are excluded from your schema (several Java regular expressions, separated by comma).
              Excludes match before includes -->
      <excludes></excludes>
    </database>

    <target>
      <!-- The destination package of your generated classes (within the destination directory) -->
      <packageName>my.package</packageName>

      <!-- The destination directory of your generated classes -->
      <directory>./src</directory>
    </target>
  </generator>
</configuration>
```

I also could not find any hints, when I took a look at the schema under http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-2.5.0.xsd

Right now it looks like I have to give up on using JOOQ :(

Edit: I use Eclipse to generate the JOOQ code, like explained in: http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.0/manual/code-generation/codegen-configuration/ under "Run code generation from Eclipse".

Comment: If you got a client key from anyone else you should throw it away. It is insecure. You should generate your own private key. Otherwise it cannot perform the function for which it is intended.

Comment: Hi EJP. My problem is, that I have great time constraints and I can not dig into the DB topic too much - I don't really like to work this way, but I'm trapped this time. Right now I'm just trying to make it work to keep my deadline... I got these files from the database owner and thought, the client-key is like a password, which I need to use. But I will try to read more about SSL - thanks for the hint, that I'm using it wrong and that I have a wrong understanding. No solution, but also a very valuable info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a more special way to set up your database connection, the right way to go forward is probably by using programmatic code generation configuration. This is documented here:

http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-programmatic/

We (unfortunately) hadn't explicitly documented this yet, but you can pass a JDBC connection explicitly to the `GenerationTool` by calling `setConnection()`

Comment: That worked out perfectly, Thank you Lukas! I will extend my question with the solution that worked for me now - for reference...

Comment: @Kai: Glad to see that it helped! Note that the usual way to do this on Stack Overflow is to provide your own answer to your question. It will be easier for future visitors of this question to understand how you come to realise your solution (nice solution btw)

Comment: Oh, I thought it would be nicer/better to accept your answer and not my own, which would be based and you answer ;) I'll keep that in mind for the next time.

Comment: @Kai: Even if I appreciate the effort, I'm already quite happy with my own amount of rep here on Stack Overflow :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution, based on the accepted answer of Lukas Eder**

After [creating the truststore and keystore](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68957) (scroll down to [17 Apr 2013 9:04] Alexander Soklakov), I could generate the code with the following class, where I get an SSL database connection and use it for the JOOQ Generator:

```
import java.sql.Connection;

import org.jooq.util.GenerationTool;
import org.jooq.util.jaxb.Configuration;
import org.jooq.util.jaxb.Database;
import org.jooq.util.jaxb.Generator;
import org.jooq.util.jaxb.Target;

import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource;

public class JooqGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        MysqlDataSource mysqlDS = new MysqlDataSource();

        mysqlDS.setUseSSL(true);
        mysqlDS.setRequireSSL(true);

        mysqlDS.setClientCertificateKeyStoreUrl(".../keystore");
        mysqlDS.setClientCertificateKeyStorePassword("keystore-pw");

        mysqlDS.setTrustCertificateKeyStoreUrl(".../truststore");
        mysqlDS.setTrustCertificateKeyStorePassword("truststore-pw");

        mysqlDS.setServerName("server");
        mysqlDS.setPort(3306);
        mysqlDS.setDatabaseName("databasename");

        Connection connection = mysqlDS.getConnection("user", "password");

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
            .withGenerator(new Generator()
                .withName("org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator")
                .withDatabase(new Database()
                    .withName("org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDatabase")
                    .withIncludes(".*")
                    .withExcludes("")
                     .withInputSchema("databasename"))
                .withTarget(new Target()
                    .withPackageName("my.package.name")
                    .withDirectory("./src")));

        GenerationTool tool = new GenerationTool();
        tool.setConnection(connection);
        tool.run(configuration);
    }
}
```